# DB2 Stored Procedure Optimizer not using the most efficient index

Tags: xml, optimization, indexing, db2

I have a stored procedure which returns data based on p_qds_startTime and p_qds_endTime parameters, which are usually set to a reporting period of 365 days, however the reporting period can be set to as little as 1 day. The table the procedure queries has many millions of rows and contains a column containing xml data.

The optimizer chooses to use an index against sys_start which can be very inefficient for 365 day reporting period. For large reporting periods, id like the optimizer to use an xml index related to policy status as there are only 300,000 records that have a policy status of 'Application'.

The policy status index is set up correctly, and if I run the underlying query, substituting the input parameters for timestamps, the explain plan shows the optimizer uses this index if the reporting period is over 10 days. If the reporting period is under 10 days, it uses the sys_start index which is also desired.

My question: is there a way to ensure the optimizer checks the input values and re-evaluates the plan it will use each time it is run? It is a once daily batch job so the overhead to do this is not really a concern.

To put it in to context, the batch job is taking up to 10 hours to run, where as when I run the underlying query locally, hitting the policy status index, it takes only a few minutes to run.

Here is the underlying query in the SP

```
select 
      policy_number
      ,year_1_commission_amount
from(
select 
      xml_policy.policy_number,
      t002.SYS_START,
      xml_policy.policy_status,
      xml_policy.year_1_commission_amount,
      ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by xml_policy.POLICY_NUMBER order by t002.SYS_START DESC) RN
from 
      DB.t002
      ,xmltable
      (
      '$i/*:AddProtQuoteResponse/*:plan[1]/*:policy[*:policyStatus = "Application"]' passing t002.QDS_XML AS "i"
      columns
      policy_number varchar(30) path '*:policyNumber',
      policy_status varchar(12) path '*:policyStatus',
      year_1_commission_amount decimal(11,2) path ''
      ) as xml_policy
where 
      sys_start > CAST(p_qds_startTime AS TIMESTAMP(12)) 
      and sys_start <= CAST(p_qds_endTime AS TIMESTAMP(12)) 
      and t002.QDS_XML_TYPE_ID = 3 
)
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to rebind the routine package with the `REOPT ALWAYS` option:

```
CALL SYSPROC.REBIND_ROUTINE_PACKAGE ('SP', 'SP_SCHEMA.SP_SPECIFICNAME', 'REOPT ALWAYS');
```

Where the 2-nd parameter is the result of:

```
SELECT RTRIM(ROUTINESCHEMA)||'.'||SPECIFICNAME
--, PARM_COUNT
FROM SYSCAT.ROUTINES R
WHERE ROUTINESCHEMA='SP_SCHEMA' AND ROUTINENAME='SP_NAME';
```

SP_SCHEMA & SP_NAME - the schema & name of your procedure. You may have a number of rows in the output of the query above (if you have a number of routines with the same this pair), and you have to choose the correct one with the corresponding specific name.

Comment: Thanks for your swift response Mark. REOPT ALWAYS looks like just what I need!

Comment: Note, that such a bind option influences all static queries in the routine. You may use dynamic SQL with constants or the corresponding optimization hint for this particular query instead of rebinding, If it's not desirable,